# PHP code not working correctly. Everything works except the qty of the first product in cart

Tags: php, html, e-commerce, cart

Like written in the title my code works okay except for the quantity for the first product when there are multiple products, where you can remove by clicking update but cant change the quantity.

```
               <?php


                include("functions/functions.php");


                 ?>

                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
                        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
                        <title>Prodavnica+</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div id="header" class="cf">
                            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
                            <div id="navbar">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="index.php"> Home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="all_products.php"> Products</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="customer/my_account.php"> My Account</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#"> Sign Up</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="cart.php"> Shopping Card</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div> <!-- END navbar -->
                            <div id="search">
                                <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input type="text" name="search_query" placeholder="Search Product" />
                                    <input type="submit" name="search_button" value="Search" />

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- END header -->
                        <?php cart(); ?>
                        <div id="shop-bar">
                            <p>
                                Total items: <?php totalItems() ?>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Total price: <?php totalPrice()?>
                            </p>
                            <a href="cart.php"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart">   | </i></a>
                            <span> Welcome Guest! </span>

                        </div> <!-- END shop-bar -->
                        <div id="container">

                            <div id="main">

                                <div id="product-box-cart">

                                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <table>

                                            <thead>
                                                <th>Product</th>
                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                                <th>Remove</th>
                                                <th>Price</th>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <?php

                                                    $total = 0;

                                                    global $con;

                                                    $ip = getIp();

                                                    $run_price = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add = '$ip'");

                                                    while($row_pro_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) {

                                                        $pro_id = $row_pro_price['p_id'];
                                                        $pro_qty = $row_pro_price['qty'];

                                                        $run_pro_price2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pro_id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

                                                        while($row_pro_price2 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price2)) {

                                                            $pro_price = array($row_pro_price2['product_price']);
                                                            $pro_title = $row_pro_price2['product_title'];
                                                            $product_image = $row_pro_price2['product_image'];
                                                            $single_price = $row_pro_price2['product_price'];



                                                            $pro_price_values = array_sum($pro_price);


                                                            $total += $pro_price_values;





                                                ?>

                                                <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <h2><?php echo $pro_title ?></h2>
                                                <img src="admin/product_images/<?php echo $product_image;?>">

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="qty[]" value = "<?php echo $pro_qty;?>">
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id ?>" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php echo "$" . $single_price; ?>
                                            </td>


                                            </tr>

                                            </tbody>


                <?php }} ?>
                                    </table>

                                    <p>
                                    <b>  Total Value: </b>  <?php  echo "$" . $total;?>
                                    </p>
                                    <div id="check-buttons">
                                    <input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart" />
                                    <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" />
                                    <a href="checkout.php"><input type="button" value="Checkout" /></a>


                                    </div>
                                </form>

                                <?php
                                //pressing update cart ->
                                if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {

                                    //removing the products
                                    if(isset($_POST['remove'])) {
                                    foreach($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id) {

                                        $delete_product = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE p_id = '$remove_id' AND ip_add = '$ip'";

                                        $run_delete = mysqli_query($con,$delete_product);

                                        if($run_delete) {

                                            echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
                                        }
                                        }
                                    }

                                        //quantity of product
                                        if(isset($_POST['qty'])) {

                                            foreach($_POST['qty'] as $qty_id) {

                                                $update_qty = "UPDATE cart SET qty = '$qty_id' WHERE p_id = '$pro_id' AND ip_add = '$ip'";

                                                $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                                            }

                                    }
                                    }


                                    elseif(isset($_POST['continue'])) {

                                    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
                                }

                                 ?>


                                </div> <!-- END product box -->

                            </div> <!-- END main -->


                            <div id="side">
                                <div id="side-category">
                                    <h2>Categories</h2>
                                    <hr />
                                    <table id="mw">
                                        <tr>
                                            <?php
                                            getBrands();

                                             ?>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                    <ul>

                                        <?php
                                        getCats();
                                         ?>

                                    </ul>
                                </div><!-- END side-category-->

                            </div> <!-- END side -->

                        </div> <!--END container -->

                        <div id="footer">
                            <p>&copy; 2018 by </p>
                        </div> <!-- END footer -->

                    </body>
                </html>
```

This is my cart.php page where the code executes. The $pro_id variable is from GET method for adding to cart. Therefore the $pro_id = $_GET[add_cart] which is in index.php. I will also include the index.php file bellow so if needed, one can take a look.

Quick answer would mean a lot. Thanks

```
             ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
                    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
                    <title>Prodavnica+</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="header" class="cf">
                        <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
                        <div id="navbar">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="index.php"> Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="all_products.php"> Products</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="customer/my_account.php"> My Account</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"> Sign Up</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="cart.php"> Shopping Card</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div> <!-- END navbar -->
                        <div id="search">
                            <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input type="text" name="search_query" placeholder="Search Product" />
                                <input type="submit" name="search_button" value="Search" />

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- END header -->
                    <?php cart(); ?>
                    <div id="shop-bar">
                        <p>
                            Total items: <?php totalItems() ?>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Total price: <?php totalPrice()?>
                        </p>
                        <a href="cart.php"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart">   | </i></a>
                        <span> Welcome Guest! </span>

                    </div> <!-- END shop-bar -->
                    <div id="container">

                        <div id="main">

                            <div id="product-box">
                                <?php



                                if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
                                getCatPro();
                            }
                                elseif(isset($_GET['brand'])) {
                                    getBrandPro();
                                }
                                else {
                                    getPro();
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div> <!-- END product box -->

                        </div> <!-- END main -->


                        <div id="side">
                            <div id="side-category">
                                <h2>Categories</h2>
                                <hr />
                                <table id="mw">
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                        getBrands();

                                         ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <ul>

                                    <?php
                                    getCats();
                                     ?>

                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- END side-category-->

                        </div> <!-- END side -->

                    </div> <!--END container -->

                    <div id="footer">
                        <p>&copy; 2018 by Djordje Stamenkovic</p>
                    </div> <!-- END footer -->

                </body>
            </html>
```

functions.php

```
            <?php
            //database connection

            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","eprodavnica");

            // function for getting ip address of the client
            /*In this PHP function, first attempt is to get the direct IP address of client’s machine, if not available then try for forwarded for IP address using HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR. And if this is also not available, then finally get the IP address using REMOTE_ADDR.*/

            function getIp()
            {
                if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
                {
                  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
                }
                elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
                {
                  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                }
                else
                {
                  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                }
                return $ip;
            }

            //adding a single product to cart

            function cart() {

                if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])) {

                    global $con;

                    $ip = getIp();

                    $pro_id = $_GET['add_cart'];

                    $run_check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add = '$ip' AND p_id = '$pro_id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0) {

                        echo "";
                    } else {

                    $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO cart (p_id, ip_add, qty) values ('$pro_id','$ip',1)") or die(mysqli_error($con));

                    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
                }
                }
            }

            //getting the total added items

            function totalItems() {
                if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])) {

                    global $con;

                    $ip = getIp();

                    $run_items = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add='$ip'");

                    $count_items = mysqli_num_rows($run_items);

                } else {
                    global $con;

                    $ip = getIp();

                    $run_items = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add='$ip'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

                    $count_items = mysqli_num_rows($run_items);
                }

                echo $count_items;

            }

            //getting the total Price of items in the cart

            function totalPrice() {

                $total = 0;

                global $con;

                $ip = getIp();

                $run_price = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add = '$ip'");

                while($row_pro_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) {

                    $pro_id = $row_pro_price['p_id'];

                    $run_pro_price2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pro_id'");

                    while($row_pro_price2 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price2)) {

                        $pro_price = array($row_pro_price2['product_price']);



                        $pro_price_values = array_sum($pro_price);


                        $total += $pro_price_values;



                    }

                }
                echo "$" . $total;
            }


            //getting the categories

            function getCats() {

                global $con;

                $run_cats = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categories");

                while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {

                    $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
                    $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

                    echo "<li>
                        <a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a>
                    </li>";
                }


            }

            //getting the brands

            function getBrands() {

                global $con;

                $run_brands = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM brands");

                while($row_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)) {

                    $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
                    $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];

                    echo "<td>

                        <a href='index.php?brand=$brand_id'>$brand_title</a>

                    </td>";
                }


            }


            //getting products on main page

            function getPro() {

                if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){
                    if(!isset($_GET['brands'])) {





                global $con;

                $run_pro = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,9");

                while($row_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)) {

                    $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
                    $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
                    $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
                    $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
                    $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
                    $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];

                        echo "
                        <div class='single-product cf'>

                        <h4><a href='#'>$pro_title</a></h4>
                        <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin/product_images/$pro_image' /></a>
                        <p>
                        Price: $ $pro_price
                        </p>

                        <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button>Add To Cart</button></a>
                        </div>

                        ";

                }
                }
            }
            }


            //getting the category products

            function getCatPro() {

                if(isset($_GET['cat'])){



                    $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];


                global $con;

                $run_cat_pro = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_cat = '$cat_id'");



                $count_cats = mysqli_num_rows($run_cat_pro);

                if($count_cats == 0) {

                    echo "<div class='no-cat'>

                    <h1> We're sorry! There are currently no products with that category. :(</h1>

                    </div>";
                } else {

                while($row_cat_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_pro)) {

                    $pro_id = $row_cat_pro['product_id'];
                    $pro_cat = $row_cat_pro['product_cat'];
                    $pro_brand = $row_cat_pro['product_brand'];
                    $pro_title = $row_cat_pro['product_title'];
                    $pro_price = $row_cat_pro['product_price'];
                    $pro_image = $row_cat_pro['product_image'];

                        echo "
                        <div class='single-product cf'>

                        <h4><a href='#'>$pro_title</a></h4>
                        <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin/product_images/$pro_image' /></a>
                        <p>
                        Price: $ $pro_price
                        </p>

                        <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button>Add To Cart</button></a>
                        </div>

                        ";

                }
                }
            }
            }

            //getting the brand products (in this case sex)

            function getBrandPro() {

                if(isset($_GET['brand'])){



                    $brand_id = $_GET['brand'];


                global $con;

                $run_brand_pro = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_brand = '$brand_id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

                $count_brands = mysqli_num_rows($run_brand_pro);

                if($count_brands == 0) {

                    echo "<div class='no-cat'>

                    <h1> We're sorry! There are currently no products for that sex. :(</h1>

                    </div>";
                } else {

                while($row_brand_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brand_pro)) {

                    $pro_id = $row_brand_pro['product_id'];
                    $pro_cat = $row_brand_pro['product_cat'];
                    $pro_brand = $row_brand_pro['product_brand'];
                    $pro_title = $row_brand_pro['product_title'];
                    $pro_price = $row_brand_pro['product_price'];
                    $pro_image = $row_brand_pro['product_image'];

                        echo "
                        <div class='single-product cf'>

                        <h4><a href='#'>$pro_title</a></h4>
                        <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><img src='admin/product_images/$pro_image' /></a>
                        <p>
                        Price: $ $pro_price
                        </p>

                        <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button>Add To Cart</button></a>
                        </div>

                        ";

                }
                }
            }

            }
```

NOTE: It works fine when one product is in the cart.

Comment: It seems you're referencing `$pro_id` in your `UPDATE` statement. Is it defined as expected?

Comment: After executing a var_dump, yes every product is defined as expected except the first product.

Comment: What are the values? Where is it defined? It looks like you only define it inside of the first `while` loops. When it comes to the `UPDATE` statement, I don't see where `$pro_id` is defined for each cart entry. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry for that, Its defined in a functions.php which i just included in the post.

Comment: But in `functions.php`, `$pro_id` seems to be defined inside of functions. The variable's [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) will be local to those functions and it can only be accessed from within them.

Comment: It shouldn't work then, yeah? But it currently works for one product and for all the other products except the first one in the cart. 
I will try defining it inside the if statement bellow..

Comment: I'm not sure, it would take some troubleshooting. It might work in certain situations because `$pro_id` is defined in the `while` loops above. The last value set in those loops will persist for later code. I'd try outputting the value each time the `UPDATE` statement is executed and figure out where the value is coming from.